# Como somar valores de PHP dentro de um "for" para trazer o total

Tags: php

Tenho a seguinte programação, que traz o preço de cada item selecionado:

```
for($x=1;$x<=4;$x++){
    if($_POST['p'.$x] != '0'){
    $sql = "SELECT produto, preco FROM produtos WHERE p = '".$px."'";
    $result = $db->query($sql);
    $obj = mysqli_fetch_object($result);
    $preco = $obj->preco;
    echo $preco.'<br/>';
    }
}
```

Ele traz por exemplo:

```
10
11
15
```

Queria que após trazer tudo isso ele somasse tudo em uma outra variavel para trazer:

```
10
11
15
36
```

Como posso fazer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simples, declara uma variável fora do for, e soma ela dentro do for.

Seguindo o teu código:

```
$total = 0;

for($x=1;$x<=4;$x++){
    if($_POST['p'.$x] != '0'){
    $sql = "SELECT produto, preco FROM produtos WHERE p = '".$px."'";
    $result = $db->query($sql);
    $obj = mysqli_fetch_object($result);
    $preco = $obj->preco;

    $total += $preco;

    echo $preco.'<br/>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Perfeito, imaginei que pudesse ser algo simples mesmo, muito obrigado!